# can not connect to Phoenix without exception?

Tags: java, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am connect to `Phoenix`, I am faced with a strange problem: in some machine I can get the connection successfully, but I can get the connection fail. But when it fails, it just `not throw any exception`, it is `blocked`, so I don't know what is wrong with this. where can I see the log?

```
public class TestPhoenix {

    private static String driver = "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver";
    private  static  String url = "jdbc:phoenix:192.168.1.91,192.168.1.50,192.168.1.60:2182";

    public static void main(String[] args)throws  Exception{

        Class.forName(driver);
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        if (driver.equals("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver")){

            properties.setProperty("phoenix.functions.allowUserDefinedFunctions","true");

        }
        Connection conn = null;
        conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);

        System.out.println(conn);
    }

}
```

I run the program with :

```
java -cp phoenix-4.5.1-HBase-1.1.jar:. TestPhoenix
```

Comment: is your zookeeper port is 2182 and not the default port 2181??

Comment: @PrasadKhode yes, it is 2182

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found the problem, I do not config host in some machine. I config `zookeeper` as follow:

```
server.1=data1:2888:3888
server.2=s5:2888:3888
server.3=s6:2888:3888
```

config `hadoop` as follow:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://s5.hadoop.ipin.com:20000</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.  Either the
  literal string "local" or a host:port for DFS.</description>
</property>
```

the problem is I do not add `data1` `s5` `s6` `s5.hadoop.ipin.com` in some machine, so my program is always trying to get these hosts, so I config `/etc/hosts` as follow:

```
192.168.1.40 s5 s4.hadoop.ipin.com
192.168.1.50 s5 s5.hadoop.ipin.com
192.168.1.60 s6 s6.hadoop.ipin.com
192.168.1.91 data91 data1
```

then I can get the connection successfully